# Java - set a size to JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a strange problem, i did two class (They are very similar), but in the first Class the setPreferredSize method, works in the other not; so i have to use (in this class) setSize() method. And this is really strange. I post my code:

In this class it works well

```
package StudentNotes;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;

import StudentNotes.TextPrompt.Show;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class CreateCourse extends JDialog {
    private JTextField tFieldCourseName;


    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public CreateCourse(JDialog mainFrame, final StudApp studAppObj) {
        super(mainFrame, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(330, 200)); //it works
        setTitle("Create a course");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        tFieldCourseName = new JTextField();
        tFieldCourseName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        tFieldCourseName.setColumns(10);
        TextPrompt tp = new TextPrompt("Course name", tFieldCourseName);
        tp.changeStyle(Font.ITALIC);
        tp.setShow(Show.ALWAYS);
        tp.setForeground(Color.GRAY);

        final JLabel lblAllertcourse = new JLabel("");
        lblAllertcourse.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        JButton btnAddCourse = new JButton("Add course");
        btnAddCourse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        lblAllertcourse.setText("");
                    }
                });

                String nameCourse = tFieldCourseName.getText();
                ArrayList<Corso> courses = studAppObj.getCorsi();

                if (nameCourse.equals("")) {
                    lblAllertcourse.setText("Insert a valid name course!");
                    t.setRepeats(false);
                    t.start();
                    return;
                }   

                for (Corso currentCourse : courses) {
                    if (currentCourse.name.toUpperCase().equals(nameCourse.toUpperCase())) {
                        lblAllertcourse.setText("This course already exist!");
                        t.setRepeats(false);
                        t.start();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                studAppObj.setCorsi(new Corso(), nameCourse);
                lblAllertcourse.setText("Course added successfully");
                t.setRepeats(false);
                t.start();
            }
        });

        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(113)
                            .addComponent(btnAddCourse))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(103)
                            .addComponent(tFieldCourseName, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(lblAllertcourse, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 304, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(46)
                    .addComponent(tFieldCourseName, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(btnAddCourse)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(lblAllertcourse)
                    .addContainerGap(44, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

in this other class setPreferredSize does not work, the JDialog doesnt have a size so it reamins small ( i can just see the title of the Dialog and not more).

```
package StudentNotes;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ListDataEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListDataListener;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class EditCourse extends JDialog {

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public EditCourse(JDialog mainFrame, final StudApp studAppObj) {
        super(mainFrame, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        //I have to use setSize
        // if i use setPreferredSize does not work
        setSize(new Dimension(330, 200));
        setTitle("Edit course");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        ArrayList<Corso> listCourses = studAppObj.getCorsi();
        listCourses.toArray();

        String[] listData = { "one", "two", "three", "four",
                              "five", "six", "seven" };
        JList list = new JList(listData);
        list.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == true) {
                    ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)e.getSource();
                    int minIndex = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
                    int maxIndex = lsm.getMaxSelectionIndex();
                    for (int i=minIndex; i<=maxIndex; i++) {
                        if (lsm.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
                            System.out.println("hai selezionato l'indice nr. "+i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        scrollPane.setSize(new Dimension(118, 40));

        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(108)
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(108, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(21)
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(87, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the second class there's no call to [pack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) method and that's why the dialog remains "small". Also take a look to this topic: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: @dic19 thank you i didnt see it...

Comment: You're welcome! I've just put my comment as an answer so feel free to click in that green tick :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the second class there's no call to [pack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) method and that's why the dialog remains "small":

> `public void pack()`
>
> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts
>   of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are
>   automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the
>   minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize
>   method.
>
> If the window and/or its owner are not displayable yet, both of them
>   are made displayable before calculating the preferred size. The Window
>   is validated after its size is being calculated.

You should also take a look to this topic: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)